# How to use % to match tag in html with ideaVim

Tags: ideavim

Vim plugins do not work with ideaVim. Is there a way to get match tags like "matchit" in ideaVim.

Answer (score 5):

I think the simplest way is `vat` on tag and then use `o` to jump

Update: From version 1.8.0 it's possible with `set matchit`

Comment: There are many other useful plugin for ideavim https://github.com/JetBrains/ideavim/wiki/Emulated-plugins

Comment: I inserted `set matchit` into .ideavimrc and sourced it, then tried pressing `%` on a tag. It didn't work. I did not jump to the matching tag element.

Answer (score 4):

IdeaVim doesn't support Vim plugins since it doesn't contain a full Vim Script interpreter and its window models is quite different. There is a new initiative however to add *emulations* of popular Vim plugins to IdeaVim. For example, the vim-surround emulation is being developed in the master branch. Feel free to create a feature request at [IdeaVim's bug tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/VIM).

Answer (score 1):

One possible workaround is to go into visual mode <kbd>shift+v</kbd> and then select the next matching tag by pressing <kbd>*</kbd> or <kbd>#</kbd>.

Vim surround shortcuts will work.

- dit: delete within the tag
- dat: delete including the tag
- cit: change within the tag
- cat: change including the tag
- yit: copy within the tag
- yat: copy including the tag